# I have excel 2007 32 bits installed on the sql server on 64 bits server

Tags: excel, csv, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have EXCEL 2007 32 bits installed on 64 bits of the SQL SERVER 2014.When I am trying to run SSIS package , using SQL server agent job on SQL server 2014, i am getting error "object reference not set to the instance of the object".i have written a small program in SSIS to convert EXCEL 2007 into CSV file and i am reading from that CSV files and inserting data into SQL SERVER.
my package is not able to read that excel file from ftp folder and convert into CSV ,i get object reference error
i have fully insured the following things as mentioned below:
1)the proxy account under which my job is running has full access to the folder from where i am reading that excel file.
I am not able to read that excel file but my package is able to work properly in BIDS.The CSV file is created properly.but when running that package through job my ssis package is not able to read the excel file.
any help appreciated.

Comment: Remove the 32-bit installation and reinstall using the optional 64-bit installation. See [Choose the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2DEE7807-8F95-4D0C-B5FE-6C6F49B8D261).

Comment: i will try tht but what is the actual problem

Comment: my code for converting excel to csv is written in ssis package which will execute in ssis environment which is 32 bits.i will then use my jobs to run the package so stiil i should use 64 bits of excel